# how to reuse list in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, list, queue

i have a threaded class with queue of `list<string>`. when i push a list from main in threaded class queue in Java list pass by reference. so when next time i use that list list again with clear my thread side queue's list also clear.

```
list<int> my-list=new array list<int>();
obj.push(my-list); //obj is thread class obj.
```

next time how to use my-list so thread side no impact on list.

if i again use `my-list.clear();` and `obj.push(my-list);` thread side clear data should i every time create new list ?

Comment: Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. If you re-use the list you will get exactly the behaviour you are complaining about. You need a new list.

Answer (score 2):

> should i every time create new list ?

Yes you should.  If you don't and you change the list, then you will (inevitably) be modifying the list that that you enqueued previously.

When you put a Java object into a `Queue` (or indeed, and other collection framework data structure) it *doesm't* copy it.  Your code has to take that into account.

---

Actually, it is worse that that.  Since you are talking about a multi-threaded application, there can be problems with calling (say) `clear` on the queue even if you intended it to change the list in the queue.

The problem is that unless the operations on the list are properly synchronized, another thread that is reading the list won't necessarily see a consistent version of the list.  It might not see the updates at all, but worse than that, it might see an inconsistent view of the list; e.g. the "size" it sees might not match the actual number of elements in the list.  (And that's even with the reader and writer not doing things simultaneously ...)

---

> ```
>   for(0---5){
>     list<int> my-list=new array list<int>(); 
>     obj.push(my-list); //obj is thread class obj. 
>   }
> ```
>
> what will happen when my code out of for loop all 5 list will destroy
>   from thread queue.

What happens is that the 5 list objects that you created will remain in the queue.  They are not destroyed.

In Java, objects are not (ever) "destroyed" when the variables that reference them go out of scope.  At most, they *might* become *eligible* for garbage collection ... if there are no remaining reachable references to them.  But in your example, there will be references in the `obj` queue ... because you just added them ... and the `obj` queue itself is reachable because `obj` is a `static` field (you said).

Basically, if your program can still find a reference to an object, it won't be destroyed.

> or every time same name list creation is correct ?

I'm not sure what you are asking here ...

Comment: thanks i am agree can u more explorer my issue for(0---5){list<int> my-list=new array list<int>();
obj.push(my-list); //obj is thread class obj. } what will happen when my code out of for loop all 5 list will destroy from thread queue. or every time same name list creation is correct ?

Comment: every time same name list creation is correct ? i mean to say i am allocating memory for list and pushing in queue so same name object of list will create new list and push as new list reference ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"same name object of list"*?  Lists don't have names.  In general objects don't have names in Java.  (Are you using Google translate or something to translate your comments into English?)